# How to implement Auto Text search in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add text search to my webpage.but i want it to search automatically
when the user enter the text without clicking on find button. i want to remove button and make it auto search

example code

```js
function doSearch(text) {
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        document.designMode = "on";
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);
        
        while (window.find(text)) {
            document.getElementById("button").blur();
            document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");
            sel.collapseToEnd();
        }
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        while (textRange.findText(text)) {
            textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
            textRange.collapse(false);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="button" onmousedown="doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" value="Find">

<div id="content">
    <p>Here is some searchable text with some lápices in it, and more lápices, and some <b>for<i>mat</i>t</b>ing</p>
</div>
```

Comment: [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput).

Comment: Have you tried removing the button and watching events on the textbox?  Please show us your progress beyond your initial state.

Comment: i have tried but it's not working can you change the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
<input type="text" id="search" onkeypress="doSearch(this.value)">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp